# How to detect if a string contains at least a number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to detect if a string contains at least a number (digit) in SQL server 2005?

Comment: Do you mean a substring, or is a number greater than or equal to a specified values?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

[MSDN - LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: I thought square brackets escaped in MSSQL, such as `LIKE '[_]'`? Also out of interest where did you find this information?

Comment: No this does work, I've been doing it for years and have no idea where I first saw it...

Comment: @CodeBlend square brackets are used for escaping when *outside* a string, and for delimiting patterns when *inside* a string.

Comment: The square brackets in a LIKE statement are explained here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Note that you must use [0-9] as shown and not the Regex shorthand [\d] for digit.  Worked for me - up vote.

Answer (score 13):

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @str = 'PONIES!!...pon1es!!...p0n1es!!'

IF PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @str) > 0
   PRINT 'YES, The string has numbers'
ELSE
   PRINT 'NO, The string does not have numbers'
```

Comment: Why PATINDEX, rather than a simple LIKE?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'FDAJLK' LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END;  -- False
SELECT CASE WHEN 'FDAJ1K' LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END;  -- True
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use CLR based UDFs or do a CONTAINS query using all the digits on the search column.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers didn't work for me.
But this helped me:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column SIMILAR TO '%[0-9]%'
```

Works in psql

Comment: Tanteriiia, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment). It's currently unclear how this would solve the original question. If you think your answer is valid please provide enough details to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

I used patindex to check for 1 digits in the string

```
select
case when  PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Description)>0 then
'found'
else
'not found'
end digits
from myTable
```