# Check if a variable contains any non-numeric digits in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I've a query like below:-

```
DECLARE @rptID VARCHAR(8)
SET @rptID = (SELECT reportID FROM Reports)
```

In general **@rptID** contains numeric digits like '00001234' etc. But is there any way to validate if the variable **@rptID** contains any non-numeric value in it.

For ex.

```
IF (@rptID contains non-numeric value)
            THEN throw Error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if a string contains atleast a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558825/how-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-atleast-a-number)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28370295/1369235

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check for any characters that are not in the range 0 to 9

[`^` is not in LIKE expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

```
IF @rptID LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
   --throw error
```

Comment: Your string lacks the ending '

Comment: Just for my own future reference: `LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` will consider blank as integer while `NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'` will consider it as non integer.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an `ISNUMERIC` function in MSSQL if you're using version 2008 or later.

[mentioned link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
IF (not ISNUMERIC(@rptID) = 1)
    THEN throw Error
```