# the basics of the like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do i write a query to retrieve a pattern of exactly five letters.
I have this question to answer :
List all the Customer name whose names are formed by exactly 5 letters. 
The query i wrote is like this :

```
SELECT ContactName
From Customers
 WHERE ContactName LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'
```

Thank you

Comment: That seems reasonable.  If you have a case sensitive collation, you might want to include lower case too.

Comment: There are multiple ways. The way you have done is one. You could also use `LEN()` and the `LIKE` operator. Something like... `ContactName not like '%[^a-z]%' and Len(ContactName) = 5`

Comment: To address case sensitive collation, in my above comment just add `Lower(ContactName)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ContactName
FROM Customers
WHERE LEN(ContactName) = 5 AND ContactName Not LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND ContactName Not LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

I haven't tested it but it should work

My Approach is Check the Length which should be equal to 5 and should not contain any number or special character.

I took help form the 
[How to detect if a string contains at least a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558825/how-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-at-least-a-number)

And also reference from
[How to detect if a string contains special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558755/how-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-special-characters) 
And read

https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-not-like-operator-in-sql

Comment: ContactName should be 5 *letters*, not any character, but letters

Comment: Another And with Not LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'

Comment: @Martin I have updated the answer and added reference to where the code was taken from so it will be helpful to other users

Comment: Your final two arguments are counter productive ; you're setting if column is NOT number and then you are checking if the column is a Number or a letter.... make your mind up!

Comment: @Martin look closely its %[^a-zA-Z0-9]% with a ^

Comment: well that's a double negative; why not remove both the negatives and simply the result? *NOT like NOT this pattern*

Comment: And if you're doing the same thing twice, you can simply remove the first ` Not LIKE '%[0-9]%'` clause entirely as that is caught in the second clause!

Comment: first clause it the check for numbers and the second clause is the check for special characters

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ContactName
FROM Customers
WHERE LEN(ContactName) = 5
```

Comment: ContactName should be 5 letters, not any character, but letters.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT ContactName
From Customers
WHERE ContactName LIKE '_%_%_%_%_%'
```

Any character with length 5

Comment: This would return false positives too for characters that are not letters.

Comment: Because of the "%", this will match *at least* t chars